# Adding Leverage browser caching to facebook widget

Tags: facebook, caching

I've added most of the leverage browser cache after reading many updates but this one keeps popping up.
Leverage browser caching for the following cacheable resources:
http://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js (20 minutes)

Now i've found the path in the file which does it where can i manually add a bit of code to it and which code do I need to use?

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/<?php echo get_locale(); ?>/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3&appId=123456789";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind - I found out there is nothing I can do as it's controlled by facebook their end. Unless I remove the facebook widget I have to put up with it.